# How to get output variable's value in next VSTS task?

Tags: powershell, build, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I'm using this command to set the output variable in a task-1

```
Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable= buildOutcome;]$buildOutcome")
```

and trying to access this variable using the following commands (in a series of tasks, task-3 is next to next of task-1)

```
$(buildOutcome)

$env:buildOutcome

$(task-1.buildOutcome)
```

But there is no output all variables value are null.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try removing the leading space? `variable= buildOutcome;`

Comment: Yes, Let me try one more time after removing leading space.

Comment: @daniel, After removing it worked- Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a leading space between the equals sign and the variable name:

```
Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable= buildOutcome;]$buildOutcome")
#                                              ^ extraneous space
```

Remove it:

```
Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildOutcome;]$buildOutcome")
```